# Can't get Task.Result to return string unless I add a Thread.Sleep

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

First time asking a question here I'll try to be as specific as possible.

I am working with a WebBased Api at work and I am having a difficult time getting the Task to return a result.

I have a trade class as such with a Buy method and a GetOrderNumber method.  On my MainForm I am using a Task to execute the Trade and then retrieve the ordernumber associated with that trade.

```
NewTrade Test = new NewTrade();

Task<string> tmp = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Test.Buy("JPM.NY", 100, 59.50));
string reqid = tmp.Result;

Task<string> tmp2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Test.GetOrderNumber(reqid));

Console.WriteLine(tmp2.Result);
```

The First Task returns a REQID number.  The second Task uses the REQID number and returns the actual ORDER NUMBER for the Trade Placed.

The problem I'm running into is I get the ReqID number from the first task but I return blank on the second task.

IF HOWEVER I add a Thread.sleep() between the first and second task I get the ordernumbers.

I'm using Tasks becasue eventually there will be hundreds of orders being placed it's critical to have the ordernumber for every order.

```
class NewTrade
{ 
   public string Buy(string stkName, int stkShares, double limitPrice)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient())
            {

                Stream data = client.OpenRead("http://localhost:8080/ExecuteOrder?symbol=" + stkName + "&limitprice=" + limitPrice + "&ordername=ARCA%20Buy%20ARCX%20Limit%20DAY&shares=" + stkShares);
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
                string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                s = getBetween(s, "<Content>", "</Content>"); //this is a util function to parse the result
                // MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());
                data.Close();
                reader.Close();

                return s;
            }
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            return "Nothing";
        }
    }

    public string GetOrderNumber(string id)
    {
        string s = "";

        using (MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080/GetOrderNumber?requestid=" + id);
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(s);
                return s;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                return "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Valmorgal then [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26226337/edit) and make it show that. Also use @ not - to make comments noticeable by the user you are talking to. Please make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of your problem, something we can just copy the code and run it ourselves to see it happening would be best (can you replicate the problem without the WebClient call?)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain will do.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I've been trying various things as the OrderNumber method is right now it's using the webrequest to get the response from the local webserver and it is the same issue.  I've also used the WebClient and also the same issue.

Comment: 1) Why are you using tasks then immediately doing `Task.Result`, you are just slowing things down by waiting for tasks to spin up. You would get better performance of running the code directly without a task at all. 2) What happens if you fake it and just hard code a string response, does it still happen then? Try to make the problem as simple as possible and still re-recreate the problem.

Comment: This should be using `async` and `await` calls, I think.

Comment: If I hard code the reqID, then it works fine. (ie, Task<string> tm2 = Task.Factor.StartNew(()=> Test.GetOrderNumber("129"), it returns the ordernumber every time;

Comment: I'm using Tasks, as this will be executing 100's of orders eventually, should I be looking at something else?

Comment: You say hardcoding the reqID works fine. Are you sure the method `Buy` isn't throwing an exception?

Comment: When I said hard code it, I meant temporarly change the code for `Buy` to `public string Buy(string stkName, int stkShares, double limitPrice) { return "129"; }` And, no Tasks are fine for simultainous things, but you cant use `.Result` the next line after you start the task if you plan on doing that. Your whole system will need a re-design for handling multiple at the same time.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez Buy isn't throwing an exception, actually Buy works fine I always get the reqID...

Comment: @ScottChamberlain yeah if I hard code the response it still gives me a blank response.

Comment: I've noticed something if I remove all the Task and just create a new NEWTRADE and execute a Buy and attempt to get the OrderNumber I still have to sleep the Thread for 40-50 before I can get the OrderNumber.

Comment: I'm getting a Http Response code 204 if I try to get the OrderNumber after I requst the ReqID....however if I put the sleep in then I get the OrderNumber...anyone have any ideas why?  Is it the WebClient? KeepAlive...I am at a lost here

Comment: You are swallowing exceptions inside `GetOrderNumber`. Have you tried setting a breakpoint inside the `catch` block to see if any occur?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I have....but it never triggers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Task`s can make your application more scalable as you are enabling threads to handle other tasks while the asynchronous task is in progress.  That being said, using     `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` to do IO  tasks in the background defeats that purpose. You need to make your methods truly `async` by calling the `async` API of the IO constructs you are using. Try changing your code to something like this:

```
public Task<string> MakeTradeAsync()
{
    NewTrade Test = new NewTrade();

    string reqid = await Test.Buy("JPM.NY", 100, 59.50);

    string orderNumber = await Test.GetOrderNumber(reqid);

    Console.WriteLine(orderNumber);

    return orderNumber;
}
```

That will require you to make `Test.Buy` and `Test.GetOrderNumber` async as well. Which you can do by using `async` APIs to access your server data.

```
 public async Task<string> Buy(string stkName, int stkShares, double limitPrice)
 {
    try
    {
        using (MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient())
        {
            // use async API here to get the data, assuming existance of OpenReadAsync
            Stream data = await client.OpenReadAsync("http://localhost:8080/ExecuteOrder?symbol=" + stkName + "&limitprice=" + limitPrice + "&ordername=ARCA%20Buy%20ARCX%20Limit%20DAY&shares=" + stkShares);
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(data);
            string s = reader.ReadToEnd();
            s = getBetween(s, "<Content>", "</Content>"); //this is a util function to parse the result
            // MessageBox.Show(s.ToString());
            data.Close();
            reader.Close();

            return s;
        }
    }
    catch (WebException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        return "Nothing";
    }
}

public async Task<string> GetOrderNumber(string id)
{
    string s = "";

    using (MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8080/GetOrderNumber?requestid=" + id);
            WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync();
            var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            s = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(s);
            return s;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using the suggested changes, but still encountering the problem of blank return.  If I Thread.Sleep(50) in the OrderNumber Method at the beginning everything works fine....which I have no idea why...

Comment: There may be some asynchronous operation happening on the server, so doing the sleep causes it to complete in time for the next call.  I'd look at what happens on the server side when you call `client.OpenRead`

Comment: Talked to one of the other Traders and they are able to pull from the same server in 2 milliseconds after the Trade is executed.  He's using python though...

Comment: Maybe their query is different? Try using the same url if you can, that may narrow it down

Comment: I looked at it, we all have a standard query.  I went through checking if I made a typo..but nothing but it works if I add the delay..it's almost like after the first httprequest to the webserver it just hangs for a bit then once it exits I am able to execute the OrderNumber method and receive the ordernumber...

Comment: Can you use `MyWebClient` to get the order number?

Comment: Anyone notice the `catch all and return an empty string?` Either there's an exception raised or the server *does* return an empty string

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've breakpoint on that and it never gets to that part of the code...